# Oracle 1.2 ListAgg with keep (dense_rank) gives extra comma in the list

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

I am using `KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST)` analytic function to get the last value in a group, and I'm further using the `LISTAGG` function to generate a list from the previous results. A strange thing is there is an extra delimiter at the end of the list. Does anyone know why, or is this a bug in Oracle?

Here is a simplified demonstration:

```
with mydata as (
  select to_date('4/1/2015','mm/dd/yyyy') next_due, 51528 cust_id from dual
   union all select  to_date('4/1/2015','mm/dd/yyyy'), 5364 from dual
   union all select  to_date('4/3/2015','mm/dd/yyyy'), 51468 from dual
), i1 as (
  select cust_id, 
         max(next_due) keep (dense_rank last order by next_due) max_date
    from mydata
   group by cust_id
)
select max_date, 
       listagg(cust_id||',') within group (order by 1) maxdate_list
  from i1
 group by max_date
```

and the result is

```
MAX_DATE   MAXDATE_LIST   
---------- ---------------
04/01/2015 51528,5364,    
04/03/2015 51468,
```

Notice the unwanted comma at the end of each `MAXDATE_LIST`? The same thing also happens if I switch to `FIRST_VALUE() OVER (PARTITION...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't concatenate the comma yourself using `||`.  you need to pass it as a parameter to `listagg`:

```
listagg(cust_id, ',')
```

Comment: That was an easy one! Duh! Thanks sstan